# Error deploying .Net Core 3.0 Web API to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt, asp.net-core-3.0

I recently upgraded my ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API to .Net Core 3.0.
Now, when I publish to Azure App Service from within Visual Studio 2019 Community (latest updates installed) I get this message:

**There was a problem starting PropWorx.API on propworx-api-san.
Your application requires the .NET Core 3.0.0 runtime, but Microsoft Azure App Service only supports the following versions: 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.2.6, 2.2.7 and 3.0.0.**

[image]

Yet, the API appears to work just fine once deployed. Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry much about it as its just a warning, You can keep track on the latest releases on the ASP.NET Core on [`App Service Dashboard`](https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. I see that in South Africa North, where my API is hosted, .Net Core 3.0 is partially current: "The runtime and shared frameworks are there, but the .NET SDK is missing. You can run 3.0, but not build 3.0."